# Excel Chart has no title error

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm working with VBA trying to make charts.
The chart is created like it should, but when I try to define a title, I get this error: 
       "run time error '-2147024809 (80070057): this object has no title."

my VBA line is:

```
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "From " & Cells(Start, Prev) & " To " & Cells(Start, Op) & " - Recomended Setup: 0"
```

Does anyone has any idea why It's not working?
(the same line worked on another chart already...) 
Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is because you need to create the title before you can set it. Add this line before your code

```
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "From " & Cells(Start, Prev) & _
                              " To " & Cells(Start, Op) & _
                              " - Recomended Setup: 0"
```